# read csv file with special linebreaks

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have to read a CSV file with somehow funny line breaks into a dataframe. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

```
with open(fileToRead,'r') as file:
     filedata = file.read().replace("#@#@#", "\n")
     file.close()
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=StringIO(filedata), sep='~')
```

The code works but I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

Is there a possibility to do this without storing the file into the `filedata` variable?

Comment: Note that `file.close` is: 1. A typo, as you're missing the parentheses that would call it and actually *do anything*; and 2. Redundant, as you're using the `with` context manager.

Comment: `read_csv` has a line-terminator option but it can be only one character long. Your case seems different

Comment: I'm not sure if the standard library `csv` module accepts multi character line terminiators, either. What do you think is wrong with your current solution? If you don't have any control over what the input file looks like in the first place, this seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks jonsharpe for the hint with the close.

Comment: currently the loading process is rather slow - so I thought it might speed up a bit if I can replace the linebreaks "on the fly" instead of pushing it through the filedata variable first.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively try the following code, which will make a copy of the data with more "normal" linebreaks.

```
with open('{}.clean'.format(fileToRead), 'w') as out_file:
    with open(fileToRead, 'r') as in_file:
         in_file_data = in_file.read().replace('#@#@#', '\n')
         out_file.write(in_file_data)

df = pandas.read_csv('{}.clean'.format(fileToRead), sep='~')
```

but really, the method you currently use is fine.

Also, as indicated by @jonrsharpe, you don't need to explicitly close files when you open them with the `with` statement. Files will automatically close once the code leaves the scope of the `with` statement.